# Does MonetDBLite support auto-commit mode?

Tags: r, monetdblite

I am trying to optimize data upload in an R package using `MonetDBLite`. As per the [MonetDB website](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/CopyInto), using `LOCKED` mode can speed up upload:

> LOCKED mode
>
> In many bulk loading situations, the original file can be saved as a
>   backup or recreated for disaster handling. This reliefs the database
>   system from having to prepare for recovery as well and to safe
>   significant storage space. The LOCKED qualifier can be used in this
>   situation (and in single user mode!) to skip the logging operation
>   normally performed.

However, when I try to run my `COPY INTO` statement with `LOCKED` mode I get the error:

```
Server says 'ParseException:SQLparser:COPY INTO .. LOCKED: only allowed in auto commit mode'.
```

Reading the [CRAN MonetDBlite documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MonetDBLite/MonetDBLite.pdf) would have me believe that the standard mode is auto-commit, eg. the documentation for `dbTransaction()`:

> dbTransaction is used to switch the data from the normal
>   auto-commiting mode into transactional mode. Here, changes to the
>   database will not be permanent until dbCommit is called. If the
>   changes are not to be kept around, you can use dbRollback to undo all
>   the changes since dbTransaction was called.

but perhaps this isn't true since I'm getting the above error.

Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: for now this is not supported but the next version of MonetDBLite (0.4.0) will

Comment: OK, thanks @HannesMühleisen! I have a few more questions about optimization in MonetDBLite, with regards to PRAGMA, prepared statements, etc. I can't find information on that in the MonetDBLite documentation, do you have another location where that info could be, or should I open a new  question?

Comment: what is it that you want to do? Prepared statements are coming in the next version as well.